# Parsing Large File in C

Tags: c, linux

For a class, I've been given the task of writing radix sort in parallel using pthreads, openmp, and MPI. My language of choice in this case is C -- I don't know C++ too well.

Anyways, the way I'm going about reading a text file is causing a segmentation fault at around 500MB file size. The files are line separated 32 bit numbers:

```
12351
1235234
12
53421
1234
```

I know C, but I don't know it well; I use things I know, and in this case the things I know are terribly inefficient. My code for reading the text file is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

 if(argc != 4) {
   printf("rs_pthreads requires three arguments to run\n");
   return -1;
 }

 char *fileName=argv[1];
 uint32_t radixBits=atoi(argv[2]);
 uint32_t numThreads=atoi(argv[3]);

 if(radixBits > 32){
   printf("radixBitx cannot be greater than 32\n");
   return -1;
 }

 FILE *fileForReading = fopen( fileName, "r" );
 if(fileForReading == NULL){
   perror("Failed to open the file\n");
   return -1;
 }
 char* charBuff = malloc(1024);

 if(charBuff == NULL){
   perror("Error with malloc for charBuff");
   return -1;
 }

 uint32_t numNumbers = 0;
 while(fgetc(fileForReading) != EOF){
   numNumbers++;
   fgets(charBuff, 1024, fileForReading);
 }

 uint32_t numbersToSort[numNumbers];

 rewind(fileForReading);
 int location;
 for(location = 0; location < numNumbers; location++){
   fgets(charBuff, 1024, fileForReading);
   numbersToSort[location] = atoi(charBuff);
     }
```

At a file of 50 million numbers (~500MB), I'm getting a segmentation fault at rewind of all places. My knowledge of how file streams work is almost non-existent. My guess is it's trying to malloc without enough memory or something, but I don't know.

So, I've got a two parter here: How is rewind segmentation faulting? Am I just doing a poor job before rewind and not checking some system call I should be?

And, what is a more efficient way to read in an arbitrary amount of numbers from a text file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `rewind()` doesn't malloc anything, it just places the file pointer back to the begining... what was the exact information when the seg fault occured?

Comment: @Mike He probably trashed the stack (more accurately trashed something adjacent to the stack) on the line just before `rewind()` by allocating a gigantic stack-based array.

Comment: You really need to provide a SCCE that demonstrates the problem.  Code fragments are not helpful. `numbersToSort` is likely to be the problem. Not certain though. Is it big enough? When you malloc`ed it did you multiply by `sizeof(int)` Or there's something else wrong with your code that's overwriting `fileForReading` on the stack.  This is what causes `rewind` to die.  Why not just use `scanf` rather than reading strings?

Comment: @Gene He didn't `malloc` it, he allocated it on the stack. Read the code (then read my answer).

Comment: @dvnrrs Ah, thanks. I was looking for the declaration at the top of the function. Did not see it in the middle. Still it is unusual for the code to run through part of the array before faulting. Normally the fault occurs at the point where the function is called.

Comment: @Gene It isn't failing partway through; he stated the fault occurs at `rewind()`. When he said "at ... 50 million numbers" he meant the program works on smaller files, but fails on larger files. This is consistent with the stack overflow theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most likely cause here is (ironically enough) a *stack overflow*. Your `numbersToSort` array is allocated on the stack, and the stack has a fixed size (varies by compiler and operating system, but 1 MB is a typical number). You should dynamically allocate `numbersToSort` on the heap (which has much more available space) using `malloc()`:

```
uint32_t *numbersToSort = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * numNumbers);
```

Don't forget to deallocate it later:

```
free(numbersToSort);
```

I would also point out that your first-pass loop, which is intended to count the number of lines, will fail if there are any blank lines. This is because on a blank line, the first character is `'\n'`, and `fgetc()` will consume it; the next call to `fgets()` will then be reading the following line, and you'll have skipped the blank one in your count.

Comment: To me that seems like one of the cases where a VLA is used accidentally and the user is bitten by it.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give that a try when I have access to the data file again. It makes sense since the file for 1 million integers didn't cause this problem and that would have been well under 1MB. And I know a blank line will ruin my strategy. Luckily I can assume no blank line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
uint32_t numbersToSort[numNumbers];
```

You are attempting to allocate a huge array in stack, your stack size is in few KBytes (Moreover older C standards don't allow this). So you can try this

```
uint32_t *numbersToSort; /* Declare it with other declarations */


/* Remove uint32_t numbersToSort[numNumbers]; */
/* Add the code below */
numbersToSort = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * numNumbers);
if (!numbersToSort) {
     /* No memory; do cleanup and bail out */
     return 1;
}
```